# System.Net.Sockets send vs stdcall:send

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, char, byte

I'm writing writing two programs, one in c# and one in c++, to send data over a socket connection.

Both programs run, both return the same expected value of `iResult`, but only the c++ program controls the device that I'm communicating with.

When I look at the values for `SendData` in debug mode in the watch, there are some differneces. For example:

```
SendData[0] = 143 // c# result
SendData[0] = -113 ' ' //c++ result
```

**Question: Is this a difference in `byte[]` vs `char[]`, or is the difference in how the send method is implemented?**

c++:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET MainSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
char SendData[1024];
SendData[i] =  0x8f; i = i + 1;            
SendData[i] =  0xa5; i = i + 1;
SendData[i] =  0x02; i = i + 1;
//... etc
SendData[i] =  0x60; i = i + 1;
iResult = send(MainSocket, buf, i, 0);
```

c#:

```
ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
MainSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv4);
MainSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
byte[] SendData = new byte[1024];
SendData[i] =  0x8f; i = i + 1;            
SendData[i] =  0xa5; i = i + 1;
SendData[i] =  0x02; i = i + 1;
//... etc
SendData[i] =  0x60; i = i + 1;
int iResult = MainSocket.Send(SendData, i, SocketFlags.None);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your socket type is `SocketType.Raw` for C# code, but you do not seem to properly create a TCP packet. What you end up sending is rubbish, which can't be understood by  your device or anybody expecting proper TCP packet.

Comment: Built into that senddata array is a header and checksum.  Is the c++ implementation not using a raw socket?  Also, why is senddata different between the two?

Comment: @Alex, your C++ implementation uses TCP sockets (`SOCK_STREAM`). It creates a proper TCP packet, and than fills it with user data. `SendData` is not really different. But since MSVC treats `char` as `signed char` and `0x8F` is bigger than 125, it displays this as a negative number. It would be better to use `unsigned char` for your buffer. But the underlying bit representation is still the same as in C#, with it's unsigned `byte`.

Comment: Ok, ill give this a try using sockettype.stream and protocol tcp.

Comment: Thanks, i thought you had to use raw when sending your own header and checksum.

Comment: @Alex, that depends on **what** header and **what** checksum. If you are doing your own protocol header (TCP/UDP/ICMP/etc) yes, you need raw mode. But if you are using a protocol which is already supported by socket interface, and your header and checksum is for something you are sending (*payload*), than of course you do not need raw sockets.